# How do I output or log to docker-compose output?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run docker-compose up it logs some information to the terminal and I would like to know where this information is coming from and how I might log to it.For example I would like to output each request in a php application within the container. I have tried to look online including the docker docs but have had no luck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The output in `docker-compose` is the stdout/stderr from the command the container runs. You see this with `docker run` if you don't detach, and you can get this from `docker logs` on a container you're detached from or `docker-compose logs` from a compose submitted group of containers.

Edit: evidence of this behavior:

```
$ cat docker-compose.hello-world.yml
version: '2'

services:
  hello-world:
    image: busybox
    command: "echo hello world"

$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.hello-world.yml up
Creating test_hello-world_1
Attaching to test_hello-world_1
hello-world_1  | hello world
test_hello-world_1 exited with code 0
```

Comment: I have tried writing to stdout and stderr but this does not output in the feedback from docker-compose up

Comment: You mentioned trying to write to stdout, did you actually write to stdout? Can you provide sample code where you know this is happening while you aren't seeing it in the output of docker-compose?

Comment: for example I have tried in a bash session `echo foo >>/dev/stdout` and `fwrite(STDOUT, $output);` within php

Comment: I just showed above the `echo hello world`, if you can't reproduce that, you should update your question with a complete but minimal example.

Comment: ok, great... so we ended up with a half-finished question and an accepted but unrelated answer..

Comment: @Christian unrelated answer? I'd there a different question being asked that I missed?

Comment: *"For example I would like to output each request in a php application within the container."* - how does the answer deal with that?

Comment: @Christian You output the log to stdout or stderr, same as you would with any application, docker doesn't care if it's running php or any other program. Without a [mcve] of the problem, it's not straight forward to provide an answer in code that would apply to the OP's problem.

Comment: That depends on whether the process serving the request is the same as the ENTRYPOINT/CMD. For example, in most cases one have to be careful to note that apache or nginx might be the ones that need configuring, and not PHP.
All this stuff gets even funnier when one sees `[access|error].log` files are actually links to `/dev/[stdout|stderr]`

Comment: @Christian ^ that is precisely why an [mcve] is needed to better answer this question.